# Parse dataSnapShot.getValue.toString to jsonArray having whiteSpace in String

Tags: android, arrays, string

When I get the data from `datasnapShot.getValue().toString` as my string or data have whitespace in it JSONArray does not even get the data into jsonArray. What should I do,i need to use only this method.Please gives me something or alter it so I can do my code. I'm new to coding and Android with a little bit of knowledge.

```
void updateSubjects() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("posts-by-subjects").child(selectedStream).child("subjects");
        databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ArrayList<String> subjects = new ArrayList<String>();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); // **
                    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        if (!jsonArray.get(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                            subjects.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                updateRecyclerView(subjects);
                showHideProgressDialog(false);
            }
```

Comment: post your response

Answer (score 0):

use the following java method:

```
  String str = "Your string with     spaces";
  str = str.replace(" " , "");
```

like this:

```
subjects.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString().replace(" ",""));
```

Comment: even jsonArray is not having the value of dataSnapShot then

 'JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());'